# Getting error while creating the policy IAM resource path must either be

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am getting the following error.

IAM resource path must either be "*" or start with user/, federated-user/, role/, group/, instance-profile/, mfa/, server-certificate/, policy/, sms-mfa/, saml-provider/, oidc-provider/, report/, access-report/.

Please help me out here.

Here is my code.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:StartSession"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::197709948620:instance/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "ssm:resourceTag/Finance": [
                        "Web Server"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:TerminateSession"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:session/${aws:username}-*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The following resource is incorrect:

```
arn:aws:iam::197709948620:instance/*
```

`instance` is `ec2`, not `iam`. It should be:

```
arn:aws:ec2::197709948620:instance/*
```